# remove a character from the string which does not come simultaneously in c

Tags: c, string

for example, given the string `str1 = "120jdvj00ncdnv000ndnv0nvd0nvd0"` and the character `ch = '0'`, the output should be `12jdvj00ncdnv000ndnvnvdnvd`. That is, the `0` is removed only wherever it occurs singly.
 this code is not working

```
#include<stdio.h>
char remove1(char *,char);
int main()
{
  char str[100]="1o00trsg50nf0bx0n0nso0000";
   char ch='0';

   remove1(str,ch);

   printf("%s",str);        
   return 0;
}

char remove1(char* str,char ch)
{  
  int j,i;
  for(i=0,j=0;i<=strlen(str)-1;i++)
  {
    if(str[i]!=ch)
    {
     if(str[i+1]==ch)
     continue;
 else
   str[j++]=str[i]; 
 }
}
  str[j]='\0';
}
```

Comment: what should the output string look like?

Comment: for example : str1="1200chhc0hdh0hxh00";
    ch='0';
 output is :=1200chhchdhhxh00

Comment: So why post code? Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your problem? Single-step through your function, inspect the variables … Then you will find the answer yourself probably.

Comment: i tried but i did not find solution of my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks for an occurrence of something other than the character to be removed with "if(str[i]!=ch)", then if the next character is the one to be removed it skips (i.e. does not keep the characters it has just seen), otherwise it copies the current character. So if it sees 'a0' and is looking for '0' it will ignore the 'a'.

What you could do is copy all characters other than the one of interest and set a counter to 0 each time you see one of them (for the number of contiguous character of interest you've seen at this point). When you find the one of interest increment that count. Now whenever you find one that is not of interest, you do nothing if the count is 1 (as this is the single character you want to remove), or put that many instances of the interesting character into str if count > 1.

Ensure you deal with the case of the string ending with a contiguous run of the character to be removed, and you should be fine.

Comment: try writing some using a new approach, then post it if you have further problems, explaining what they are (e.g. showing an input string and the corresponding output you get, and where it is wrong).

Comment: i am not finding another way of this prob please send me code of function

Answer (score 0):

```
char *remove1(char* str, char ch){
    char *d, *s;

    for(d = s = str;*s;++s){
        if(*s == ch){
            if(s[1] == ch)
                while(*s == ch)
                    *d++=*s++;
            else
                ++s;//skip a ch
            if(!*s)break;
        }
        *d++ = *s;
    }
    *d = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

---

Code to copy the basic

```
for(d = s = str;*s;++s){
    *d++ = *s;
}
*d = '\0';
```

Special processing to be added.

```
for(d = s = str;*s;++s){
    if(find a character that is specified){
        Copy that in the case of continuously than one character
        if one letter then skip
    }
    *d++ = *s;
}
*d = '\0';
```

Comment: @user3678787 Although I think as it is requirements, 
Is there a part you do not understand?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working code**
**output is : "1o00trsg5nfbxnnso0000"**

```
#include<stdio.h>
char remove1(char *,char);
int main()
{
        char str[100]="1o00trsg50nf0bx0n0nso0000";
        char ch='0';

        remove1(str,ch);

        printf("%s",str);    
        return 0;
}

char remove1(char* str,char ch)
{  
        int j,i;
        int len = strlen(str);

        for(i = 0;i < (len - 1);i++){
                if(str[i] == ch){

                        /* if either of check prev and next character is same then contd. without removal   */
                        if((str[i+1] == ch) || (str[i-1] == ch))
                                continue;

                        /* replacing the char and shifting next chars left*/
                        for(j = i;j < (len - 2);j++) {
                                str[j] = str[j + 1];
                        }

                        /* string length is decrementing due to removal of one char*/
                        len--; 
                }
        }
        str[len] = '\0';
}
```